# How to compare latest input with initial value using PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have class in xamarin form app and I implemented INotifyChanged on it. Later this class will be used to create a list. The data for the list comes from mysql. The list will be the item source for my third party dataGrid called sfdataGrid. The column actual reading will display integer from db and can be edited in the data grid. But the newly edited value must be bigger than the value initial value from db. Or it should revert back to initial value. How can compare the new value with initial value property Changed?

```
public class actualmeterreading : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ID;
    private string _MachineMeterReadingID;
    private Int32 _ActualReading;
    private machinemeterreadinglist _MachineMeterReadingList;

    public actualmeterreading(string id, string machinemeterreadingid, Int32 actualreading, machinemeterreadinglist machinemeterreadinglist)
    {
        this._ID = id;
        this._MachineMeterReadingID = machinemeterreadingid;
        this._ActualReading = actualreading;
        this._MachineMeterReadingList = machinemeterreadinglist;
    }

    public actualmeterreading()
    {
        this._ID = string.Empty;
        this._MachineMeterReadingID = string.Empty;
        this._ActualReading = 0;
        this._MachineMeterReadingList = new machinemeterreadinglist();
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _ID;}
        set { _ID = value;}
    }

    public string MachineMeterReadingID
    {
        get { return _MachineMeterReadingID;}
        set { _MachineMeterReadingID = value;}
    }

    public int ActualReading
    {
        get { return _ActualReading;}
        set {            
            _ActualReading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ActualReading");
        }
    }

    public machinemeterreadinglist MachineMeterReadingList
    {
        get { return _MachineMeterReadingList;}
        set { _MachineMeterReadingList = value;}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String Name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this question needs to be made more clear. You wish to compare an old and new value or is your `INotifyPropertyChanged` event handler not working as you intended?

Comment: I want to compare old value with new one, but not sure how to achieve it. The current notifypropertychanged is only to replace the inital value with new one in column. After replacing I want to check whether the new value is bigger than old value (for  example in column is int 10, if I enter 9, it should revert back to 10).

Comment: use TwoWay Binding  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int ActualReading
{
    get { return _ActualReading;}
    set {    
        // only update if new value is bigger than old value  
        if (value > _ActualReading) {      
          _ActualReading = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("ActualReading");
        }
    }
}
```